# Integrating HealthCheck endpoint into swagger (open API) UI on dotnet core

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui, openapi, asp.net-core-2.2

I am using Dotnet Core healthchecks as described [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2018/08/22/asp-net-core-2-2-0-preview1-healthcheck/?WT.mc_id=-blog-scottha). In short, it looks like this:

First, you configure services like this:

```cs
services.AddHealthChecks()
    .AddSqlServer("connectionString", name: "SQlServerHealthCheck")
    ... // Add multiple other checks
```

Then, you register an endpoint like this:

```cs
app.UseHealthChecks("/my/healthCheck/endpoint");
```

We are also using Swagger (aka Open API) and we see all the endpoints via Swagger UI, but not the health check endpoint.

Is there a way to add this to a controller method so that Swagger picks up the endpoint automatically, or maybe integrate it with swagger in another way?

The best solution I found so far is to add a custom hardcoded endpoint ([like described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48668107/add-endpoints-manually-with-swashbuckle-swagger)), but it is not nice to maintain.

Comment: Waiting for https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/18153 to be fixed

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Still looking for a better solution, but a poor man's solution to this problem looks like this:

```cs
public const string HealthCheckEndpoint = "/my/healthCheck/endpoint";

public void Apply(SwaggerDocument swaggerDoc, DocumentFilterContext context)
{
    var pathItem = new PathItem();
    pathItem.Get = new Operation()
    {
        Tags = new[] { "ApiHealth" },
        Produces = new[] { "application/json" }
    };

    var properties = new Dictionary<string, Schema>();
    properties.Add("status", new Schema(){ Type = "string" });
    properties.Add("errors", new Schema(){ Type = "array" });
    
    var exampleObject = new { status = "Healthy", errors = new List<string>()};

    pathItem.Get.Responses = new Dictionary<string, Response>();
    pathItem.Get.Responses.Add("200", new Response() {
        Description = "OK",
        Schema = new Schema() {
            Properties = properties,
            Example = exampleObject }});

    swaggerDoc.Paths.Add(HealthCheckEndpoint, pathItem);
}
```

Comment: Is there a version of this that works with Swagger 5.0.0 (using the OpenApi objects)?

Comment: @penny, I see you worked that out, thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 17):

I used this approach and it worked well for me: https://www.codit.eu/blog/documenting-asp-net-core-health-checks-with-openapi

Add a new controller e.g. HealthController and inject the HealthCheckService into the constructor. The HealthCheckService is added as a dependency when you call AddHealthChecks in Startup.cs:

The HealthController should appear in Swagger when you rebuild:

```cs
[Route("api/v1/health")]
public class HealthController : Controller
{
    private readonly HealthCheckService _healthCheckService;
    public HealthController(HealthCheckService healthCheckService)
    {
        _healthCheckService = healthCheckService;
    }
     
    /// <summary>
    /// Get Health
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>Provides an indication about the health of the API</remarks>
    /// <response code="200">API is healthy</response>
    /// <response code="503">API is unhealthy or in degraded state</response>
    [HttpGet]
    [ProducesResponseType(typeof(HealthReport), (int)HttpStatusCode.OK)]
    [SwaggerOperation(OperationId = "Health_Get")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Get()
    {
        var report = await _healthCheckService.CheckHealthAsync();

        return report.Status == HealthStatus.Healthy ? Ok(report) : StatusCode((int)HttpStatusCode.ServiceUnavailable, report);
    }
}
```

One thing I noticed though is the endpoint is still "/health" (or whatever you set it to in Startup.cs) and not "/api/vxx/health" but it will still appear correctly in Swagger.

Comment: This is the best answer IMO. I'm not sure why Microsoft doesn't document this usage in the official documentation, since there are plenty of cases where the "official" approach doesn't cut it.

Comment: You may also want to include `[AllowAnonymous]` so Swagger doesn't request credentials in order to access this endpoint.

Comment: Using `[ProducesResponseType(typeof(HealthReport), (int)HttpStatusCode.OK)]` crashes both Firefox and Chrome tabs when I try to expand the view in Swagger. I think this is because there's a circular dependency on `#/components/schemas/Exception`.

Comment: Oh, also when there's an error, JSON net cannot serialize the exception (likely because of the same circular dependency issue). I ended up creating my own DTOs for the API and mapping from the existing ones to my ones (which don't include the exception). https://github.com/harvzor/cleaning-robot-service/pull/2

Comment: Does that mean that the exception information is lost? Nice fix though! @harvzor

Answer (score 10):

Since Swagger has been updated, there's a breaking change between .NET 2.x and 3.1/Swagger 4.0.0 and 5.0.0

Below is a version of the poor man's solution (see eddyP23 answer) that works with 5.0.0.

```cs
    public class HealthChecksFilter : IDocumentFilter
    {
        public const string HealthCheckEndpoint = @"/healthcheck";
        
        public void Apply(OpenApiDocument openApiDocument, DocumentFilterContext context)
        {
            var pathItem = new OpenApiPathItem();

            var operation = new OpenApiOperation();
            operation.Tags.Add(new OpenApiTag { Name = "ApiHealth" });

            var properties = new Dictionary<string, OpenApiSchema>();
            properties.Add("status", new OpenApiSchema() { Type = "string" });
            properties.Add("errors", new OpenApiSchema() { Type = "array" });

            var response = new OpenApiResponse();
            response.Content.Add("application/json", new OpenApiMediaType
            {
                Schema = new OpenApiSchema
                {
                    Type = "object",
                    AdditionalPropertiesAllowed = true,
                    Properties = properties,
                }
            });

            operation.Responses.Add("200", response);
            pathItem.AddOperation(OperationType.Get, operation);
            openApiDocument?.Paths.Add(HealthCheckEndpoint, pathItem);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

There is no built-in support, either you manually develop a [poor man's solution like in the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54363044/4636721) or you develop an extension like mentionned in [this GitHub issue: NetCore 2.2 - Health Check Support](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/issues/1058#issuecomment-480789069)

> Swashbuckle is built on top of `ApiExplorer`, the API metadata component, that ships with ASP.NET Core.
>
> If health-checks endpoints aren't surfaced by that, then they won't be surfaced by Swashbuckle. This is a fundamental aspect to the SB design and is unlikely to change anytime soon.
>
> IMO, this sounds like a perfect candidate for a community add-on package (see https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore#community-packages).
>
> If there was a willing contributor, they could start a new project called `Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.HealthChecks`, that exposes an extension method on `SwaggerGenOptions` for enabling the functionality - e.g. `EnableHealthCheckDescriptions`. Then behind the scenes, this could be implemented as a Document Filter (see readme) that adds the relevant Operation descriptions to the `Swagger/OAI` document generated by Swashbuckle.

Answer (score 4):

***Integrating Health Check Endpoint Into Swagger (Open API) UI On .NET 5***

```cs
namespace <Some-Namespace>
{
    using global::HealthChecks.UI.Core;
    using global::HealthChecks.UI.Core.Data;

    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
    using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;
    using Microsoft.OpenApi.Any;
    using Microsoft.OpenApi.Models;

    using Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen;

    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    using static System.Text.Json.JsonNamingPolicy;

    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    public class HealthCheckEndpointDocumentFilter : IDocumentFilter
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// 
        /// </summary>
        private readonly global::HealthChecks.UI.Configuration.Options Options;

        /// <summary>
        /// 
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="Options"></param>
        public HealthCheckEndpointDocumentFilter(IOptions<global::HealthChecks.UI.Configuration.Options> Options)
        {
            this.Options = Options?.Value ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(Options));
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// 
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="SwaggerDoc"></param>
        /// <param name="Context"></param>
        public void Apply(OpenApiDocument SwaggerDoc, DocumentFilterContext Context)
        {
            var PathItem = new OpenApiPathItem
            {
                Operations = new Dictionary<OperationType, OpenApiOperation>
                {
                    [OperationType.Get] = new OpenApiOperation
                    {
                        Description = "Returns all the health states used by this Microservice",
                        Tags =
                        {
                            new OpenApiTag
                            {
                                Name = "HealthCheck"
                            }
                        },
                        Responses =
                        {
                            [StatusCodes.Status200OK.ToString()] = new OpenApiResponse
                            {
                                Description = "API is healthy",
                                Content =
                                {
                                    ["application/json"] = new OpenApiMediaType
                                    {
                                        Schema = new OpenApiSchema
                                        {
                                            Reference = new OpenApiReference
                                            {
                                                Id = nameof(HealthCheckExecution),
                                                Type = ReferenceType.Schema,
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            },
                            [StatusCodes.Status503ServiceUnavailable.ToString()] = new OpenApiResponse
                            {
                                Description = "API is not healthy"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            };

            var HealthCheckSchema = new OpenApiSchema
            {
                Type = "object",
                Properties =
                {
                    [CamelCase.ConvertName(nameof(HealthCheckExecution.Id))] = new OpenApiSchema
                    {
                        Type = "integer",
                        Format = "int32"
                    },
                    [CamelCase.ConvertName(nameof(HealthCheckExecution.Status))] = new OpenApiSchema
                    {
                        Type = "string"
                    },
                    [CamelCase.ConvertName(nameof(HealthCheckExecution.OnStateFrom))] = new OpenApiSchema
                    {
                        Type = "string",
                        Format = "date-time"
                    },
                    [CamelCase.ConvertName(nameof(HealthCheckExecution.LastExecuted))] = new OpenApiSchema
                    {
                        Type = "string",
                        Format = "date-time"
                    },
                    [CamelCase.ConvertName(nameof(HealthCheckExecution.Uri))] = new OpenApiSchema
                    {
                        Type = "string"
                    },
                    [CamelCase.ConvertName(nameof(HealthCheckExecution.Name))] = new OpenApiSchema
                    {
                        Type = "string"
                    },
                    [CamelCase.ConvertName(nameof(HealthCheckExecution.DiscoveryService))] = new OpenApiSchema
                    {
                        Type = "string",
                        Nullable = true
                    },
                    [CamelCase.ConvertName(nameof(HealthCheckExecution.Entries))] = new OpenApiSchema
                    {
                        Type = "array",
                        Items = new OpenApiSchema
                        {
                            Reference = new OpenApiReference
                            {
                                Id = nameof(HealthCheckExecutionEntry),
                                Type = ReferenceType.Schema,
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    [CamelCase.ConvertName(nameof(HealthCheckExecution.History))] = new OpenApiSchema
                    {
                        Type = "array",
                        Items = new OpenApiSchema
                        {
                            Reference = new OpenApiReference
                            {
                                Id = nameof(HealthCheckExecutionHistory),
                                Type = ReferenceType.Schema,
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            };

            var HealthCheckEntrySchema = new OpenApiSchema
            {
                Type = "object",

                Properties =
                {
                    [CamelCase.ConvertName(nameof(HealthCheckExecutionEntry.Id))] = new OpenApiSchema
                    {
                        Type = "integer",
                        Format = "int32"
                    },
                    [CamelCase.ConvertName(nameof(HealthCheckExecutionEntry.Name))] = new OpenApiSchema
                    {
                        Type = "string"
                    },
                    [CamelCase.ConvertName(nameof(HealthCheckExecutionEntry.Status))] = new OpenApiSchema
                    {
                        Reference = new OpenApiReference
                        {
                            Id = nameof(UIHealthStatus),
                            Type = ReferenceType.Schema,
                        }
                    },
                    [CamelCase.ConvertName(nameof(HealthCheckExecutionEntry.Description))] = new OpenApiSchema
                    {
                        Type = "string"
                    },
                    [CamelCase.ConvertName(nameof(HealthCheckExecutionEntry.Duration))] = new OpenApiSchema
                    {
                        Type = "string",
                        Format = "[-][d'.']hh':'mm':'ss['.'fffffff]"
                    },
                    [CamelCase.ConvertName(nameof(HealthCheckExecutionEntry.Tags))] = new OpenApiSchema
                    {
                        Type = "array",
                        Items = new OpenApiSchema
                        {
                            Type = "string"
                        }
                    },
                }
            };

            var HealthCheckHistorySchema = new OpenApiSchema
            {
                Type = "object",

                Properties =
                {
                    [CamelCase.ConvertName(nameof(HealthCheckExecutionHistory.Id))] = new OpenApiSchema
                    {
                        Type = "integer",
                        Format = "int32"
                    },
                    [CamelCase.ConvertName(nameof(HealthCheckExecutionHistory.Name))] = new OpenApiSchema
                    {
                        Type = "string"
                    },
                    [CamelCase.ConvertName(nameof(HealthCheckExecutionHistory.Description))] = new OpenApiSchema
                    {
                        Type = "string"
                    },
                    [CamelCase.ConvertName(nameof(HealthCheckExecutionHistory.Status))] = new OpenApiSchema
                    {
                        Reference = new OpenApiReference
                        {
                            Id = nameof(UIHealthStatus),
                            Type = ReferenceType.Schema,
                        }
                    },
                    [CamelCase.ConvertName(nameof(HealthCheckExecutionHistory.On))] = new OpenApiSchema
                    {
                        Type = "string",
                        Format = "date-time"
                    },
                }
            };

            var UIHealthStatusSchema = new OpenApiSchema
            {
                Type = "string",

                Enum =
                {
                    new OpenApiString(UIHealthStatus.Healthy.ToString()),
                    new OpenApiString(UIHealthStatus.Unhealthy.ToString()),
                    new OpenApiString(UIHealthStatus.Degraded.ToString())
                }
            };

            SwaggerDoc.Paths.Add(Options.ApiPath, PathItem);
            SwaggerDoc.Components.Schemas.Add(nameof(HealthCheckExecution), HealthCheckSchema);
            SwaggerDoc.Components.Schemas.Add(nameof(HealthCheckExecutionEntry), HealthCheckEntrySchema);
            SwaggerDoc.Components.Schemas.Add(nameof(HealthCheckExecutionHistory), HealthCheckHistorySchema);
            SwaggerDoc.Components.Schemas.Add(nameof(UIHealthStatus), UIHealthStatusSchema);
        }
    }
}
```

***Filter Settings***

```cs
Services.AddSwaggerGen(Options =>
{
    Options.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo
    {
        Version     = "v1",
        Title       = "<Name Api> Api",
        Description = "<Description> HTTP API."
    });

    Options.DocumentFilter<HealthCheckEndpointDocumentFilter>();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I upgraded poor man's solution into more descriptive document, which will display the response type correctly in Swashbuckle 5. I was getting the endpoint in Swagger UI, but the description in Open API Specification was clumsy. I then added the specific healthcheck datatypes to the swagger document. My solution is with a custom response writer.

Given you overwrite the response:

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllers();
            endpoints.MapHealthChecks("/heartbeat", new Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.HealthChecks.HealthCheckOptions()
            {
                ResponseWriter = HeartbeatUtility.WriteResponse
            }) ;
        });
```

Given you have the following response writer for healthchecks:

```
public static class HeartbeatUtility
{
    public const string Path = "/heartbeat";

    public const string ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
    public const string Status = "status";
    public const string TotalTime = "totalTime";
    public const string Results = "results";
    public const string Name = "Name";
    public const string Description = "description";
    public const string Data = "data";

    public static Task WriteResponse(HttpContext context, HealthReport healthReport)
    {
        context.Response.ContentType = ContentType;

        using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (var writer = new Utf8JsonWriter(stream, CreateJsonOptions()))
            {
                writer.WriteStartObject();

                writer.WriteString(Status, healthReport.Status.ToString("G"));
                writer.WriteString(TotalTime, healthReport.TotalDuration.ToString("c"));

                if (healthReport.Entries.Count > 0)
                    writer.WriteEntries(healthReport.Entries);

                writer.WriteEndObject();
            }

            var json = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(stream.ToArray());

            return context.Response.WriteAsync(json);
        }
    }

    private static JsonWriterOptions CreateJsonOptions()
    {
        return new JsonWriterOptions
        {
            Indented = true
        };
    }

    private static void WriteEntryData(this Utf8JsonWriter writer, IReadOnlyDictionary<string, object> data)
    {
        writer.WriteStartObject(Data);

        foreach (var item in data)
        {
            writer.WritePropertyName(item.Key);

            var type = item.Value?.GetType() ?? typeof(object);
            JsonSerializer.Serialize(writer, item.Value, type);
        }

        writer.WriteEndObject();
    }

    private static void WriteEntries(this Utf8JsonWriter writer, IReadOnlyDictionary<string, HealthReportEntry> healthReportEntries)
    {
        writer.WriteStartArray(Results);

        foreach (var entry in healthReportEntries)
        {
            writer.WriteStartObject();

            writer.WriteString(Name, entry.Key);
            writer.WriteString(Status, entry.Value.Status.ToString("G"));

            if (entry.Value.Description != null)
                writer.WriteString(Description, entry.Value.Description);

            if (entry.Value.Data.Count > 0)
                writer.WriteEntryData(entry.Value.Data);

            writer.WriteEndObject();
        }

        writer.WriteEndArray();
    }
}
```

Then you can have the following IDocumentFilter implementation:

```
public class HealthChecksDocumentFilter : IDocumentFilter
{
    private const string _name = "Heartbeat";
    private const string _operationId = "GetHeartbeat";
    private const string _summary = "Get System Heartbeat";
    private const string _description = "Get the heartbeat of the system. If the system is OK, status 200 will be returned, else status 503.";

    private const string _okCode = "200";
    private const string _okDescription = "Healthy";
    private const string _notOkCode = "503";
    private const string _notOkDescription = "Not Healthy";

    private const string _typeString = "string";
    private const string _typeArray = "array";
    private const string _typeObject = "object";
    private const string _applicationJson = "application/json";
    private const string _timespanFormat = "[-][d'.']hh':'mm':'ss['.'fffffff]";
    

    public void Apply(OpenApiDocument swaggerDoc, DocumentFilterContext context)
    {
        ApplyComponentHealthStatus(swaggerDoc);
        ApplyComponentHealthReportEntry(swaggerDoc);
        ApplyComponentHealthReport(swaggerDoc);

        ApplyPathHeartbeat(swaggerDoc);
    }

    private IList<IOpenApiAny> GetHealthStatusValues()
    {
        return typeof(HealthStatus)
            .GetEnumValues()
            .Cast<object>()
            .Select(value => (IOpenApiAny)new OpenApiString(value.ToString()))
            .ToList();
    }

    private void ApplyComponentHealthStatus(OpenApiDocument swaggerDoc)
    {
        swaggerDoc?.Components.Schemas.Add(nameof(HealthStatus), new OpenApiSchema
        {
            Type = _typeString,
            Enum = GetHealthStatusValues()
        });
    }

    private void ApplyComponentHealthReportEntry(OpenApiDocument swaggerDoc)
    {
        swaggerDoc?.Components.Schemas.Add(nameof(HealthReportEntry), new OpenApiSchema
        {
            Type = _typeObject,
            Properties = new Dictionary<string, OpenApiSchema>
            {
                {
                    HeartbeatUtility.Name,
                    new OpenApiSchema
                    {
                        Type = _typeString
                    }
                },
                {
                    HeartbeatUtility.Status,
                    new OpenApiSchema
                    {
                        Reference = new OpenApiReference
                        {
                            Type = ReferenceType.Schema,
                            Id = nameof(HealthStatus)
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    HeartbeatUtility.Description,
                    new OpenApiSchema
                    {
                        Type = _typeString,
                        Nullable = true
                    }
                },
                {
                    HeartbeatUtility.Data,
                    new OpenApiSchema
                    {
                        Type = _typeObject,
                        Nullable = true,
                        AdditionalProperties = new OpenApiSchema()
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private void ApplyComponentHealthReport(OpenApiDocument swaggerDoc)
    {
        swaggerDoc?.Components.Schemas.Add(nameof(HealthReport), new OpenApiSchema()
        {
            Type = _typeObject,
            Properties = new Dictionary<string, OpenApiSchema>
            {
                {
                    HeartbeatUtility.Status,
                    new OpenApiSchema
                    {
                        Reference = new OpenApiReference
                        {
                            Type = ReferenceType.Schema,
                            Id = nameof(HealthStatus)
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    HeartbeatUtility.TotalTime,
                    new OpenApiSchema
                    {
                        Type = _typeString,
                        Format = _timespanFormat,
                        Nullable = true
                    }
                },
                {
                    HeartbeatUtility.Results,
                    new OpenApiSchema
                    {
                        Type = _typeArray,
                        Nullable = true,
                        Items = new OpenApiSchema
                        {
                            Reference = new OpenApiReference
                            {
                                Type = ReferenceType.Schema,
                                Id = nameof(HealthReportEntry)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        });

    }

    private void ApplyPathHeartbeat(OpenApiDocument swaggerDoc)
    {
        swaggerDoc?.Paths.Add(HeartbeatUtility.Path, new OpenApiPathItem
        {
            Operations = new Dictionary<OperationType, OpenApiOperation>
            {
                {
                    OperationType.Get,
                    new OpenApiOperation
                    {
                        Summary = _summary,
                        Description = _description,
                        OperationId = _operationId,
                        Tags = new List<OpenApiTag>
                        {
                            new OpenApiTag
                            {
                                Name = _name
                            }
                        },
                        Responses = new OpenApiResponses
                        {
                            {
                                _okCode,
                                new OpenApiResponse
                                {
                                    Description = _okDescription,
                                    Content = new Dictionary<string, OpenApiMediaType>
                                    {
                                        {
                                            _applicationJson,
                                            new OpenApiMediaType
                                            {
                                                Schema = new OpenApiSchema
                                                {
                                                    Reference = new OpenApiReference
                                                    {
                                                        Type = ReferenceType.Schema,
                                                        Id = nameof(HealthReport)
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                _notOkCode,
                                new OpenApiResponse
                                {
                                    Description = _notOkDescription,
                                    Content = new Dictionary<string, OpenApiMediaType>
                                    {
                                        {
                                            _applicationJson,
                                            new OpenApiMediaType
                                            {
                                                Schema = new OpenApiSchema
                                                {
                                                    Reference = new OpenApiReference
                                                    {
                                                        Type = ReferenceType.Schema,
                                                        Id = nameof(HealthReport)
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Add to your swaggergen options

```
options.DocumentFilter<HealthChecksDocumentFilter>();
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, its not very pretty,

but we put the health check in a base class, and every controller inherits that class.

the base class looks something like this:

```cs
    public abstract class HealthCheckingControllerBase : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly HealthCheckService healthCheckService;

        public HealthController(
            Microsoft.Extensions.Diagnostics.HealthChecks.HealthCheckService healthCheckService)    
       {
             this.healthCheckService = healthCheckService;
       }   

       [HttpGet()]
       [Route("hc")]
       [SwaggerOperation(OperationId = "hc")]
       [Produces(MediaTypeNames.Application.Json)]
       [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
       [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status401Unauthorized)]
       [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status403Forbidden)]
       [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError, Type = typeof(ProblemDetails))]
       public ActionResult Get()
       {             
          return Ok();
       }
    }
```

and then your controller will look like :

```cs
public class MyController : HealthCheckingControllerBase
{
     MyController(HealthCheckService hcs) : base(hcs) {}

     ... endpoints...
}
```

so the code is in one place

Answer (score -4):

My workaround is to add the following dummy controller.

```cs
using HealthChecks.UI.Client;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using System;

[Route("[controller]")]
[ApiController]
[Produces("application/json")]
public class HealthController: ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet("")]
    public UIHealthReport Health()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException("");
    }
}
```